# How to autoban IPs that request URLs with a .php extension?

Tags: apache-2.2, security

I've noticed in my linux/apache server logs that bot computers running muieblackcat are periodically trying to access all forms of phpmyadmin.php on my server. It's interesting, because I have a public facing but not search engine listed or SEO'd website, which has very little content.

I have .htaccess configured to strip the .php extension from my URL so noone has a legitamate reason to search for a .php file on my domain except me.

So how can I automatically ban IPs that request .php files? It would be good if I could add an exception for myself. But it's not mega important.

Comment: fail2ban is your friend.

Comment: Automatic blocking will introduce a risk of getting hit by DoS attacks. There may be cases where an attacker and a legitimate user access you through the same IP (due to NAT or proxying). It is also possible to get legitimate users blocked by tricking them to visit a page, which sources forbidden URLs from your site.

Comment: This is very bad. This makes it easy for anyone to get anyone else banned from your site just by directing them to retrieve a link. An embedded image would do it.

Answer (score 1):

The `fail2ban` utility should do this for you.   Enable the `apache-noscript.conf` filter to catch calls to non-existent scripts.  (It will catch other scripts as well.)

`fail2ban` has variable ban times and the ability to whitelist IP addresses.

As noted in the comments to your request, it is possible to perform DoS attacks.  You should monitor what gets blocked.

If you are using `Munin` to monitor your server, you can monitor the number of addresses `fail2ban` has blocked with it.